# jump method in android game

Tags: android, game-physics

I'm new in Android Game Development and I started a simple Game in that a Droid can jump over incoming boxes. 
I want to call my droid.jump() method in the surface view with an onTouchEvent (just by a simple tap on the screen)

I created a class called Droid:

```
public class Droid {


// Log Tag for Debugging
public static final String LOG_TAG = "_1Projekt";

private Bitmap bitmap; // the actual bitmap
private int x; // the X coordinate
private int y; // the Y coordinate
private boolean touched; // if droid is touched/picked up
private Speed speed; // the speed with its directions

private long mLastTime;

public Droid(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = new Speed();
}
```

.......
...

And the jump() method is my problem. I would like to have a smooth jump but I don’t know how to calculate this with the current System Time. 
My idea was that the droid should update it Y position every –TimePeriod- and should start with a fast velocity and then decrease it to 0 to get a smooth jump. 
But I don’t know how to calculate this in my while loop.
My current jump():

```
public void jump() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Jumping");
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int elapsedTime = 100;
    int jump = y-30;

    while(y > jump)
    {
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() > now + elapsedTime)
        {
        now = now + elapsedTime;
        elapsedTime -=3;
        y = y-1;
        }
    }
}
```

Up to know I only implemented the "up" part of Jump.
Thank you for your answers! Greetings DroidDude

Comment: Maybe set a flag when your droid reach the max altitude and then just re-use your loop but decreasing the altitude instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/23967-simple-java-screen-saver/) (the third post):

> Before the mainloop, have
>
> ```
> //Get the current time
> timeStep = System.currentTimeMillis();
> ```
>
> And then do your stuff. Then before the loop goes back to start, have
>
> ```
> // Hold to lock at FPS
> while(System.currentTimeMillis()-timeStep < 1000/60);
> ```
>
> Where 60 is the frames per second to run.
>
> This method also allows you to get the difference in times after the
>   while loop in order to find out how much time it took to render one
>   frame. Using this, you could have a variable that you can multiply all
>   your increments by to get frame-independent speed.
>
> For example, if you divide the number of milliseconds it took to
>   handle the frame by 16.666, the number will equal 1 when the program
>   runs at about 60 FPS. When the frame rate is lower, it takes more
>   milliseconds to render the frame and that factor gets bigger.
>
> Be sure to put it BEFORE repaint however. This is the way video games
>   are timed also. An example is shown in my video game base applet code
>   snippet under JAVA.

Comment: That doesn't act as I supposed. I wonder how to get the actual frame rate. What I need is to decrease the acceleration during the jump.